# Trying to split strings the way str_split_n() does, but cannot call it although it is in stringr's manual and repo

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

How do I split strings here? For some reason `str_split_n` is in `stringr`'s repo, but using it is not possible. There is no help file, either.

So I'd like to use this:

```r
x <- c("a", "b[12]", "c[34]", "d")
tibble(x) |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    y = str_split_n(x, "\\[", 1)
  )
```

To get this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  x     y    
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     a    
2 b[12] b    
3 c[34] c    
4 d     d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could just use `sub` here, and remove the trailing bracketed item:

```r
df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b[12]", "c[34]", "d"))
df$y <- sub("\\[.*?\\]$", "", df$x)
df

      x y
1     a a
2 b[12] b
3 c[34] c
4     d d
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you were looking for is -

```
tibble(x) |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    y = stringr::str_split_fixed(x, "\\[", 2)[, 1]
  )

#  x     y    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 a     a    
#2 b[12] b    
#3 c[34] c    
#4 d     d
```

Comment: This also works, but I was looking for `str_split_n`, which exists, but cannot be called at all: [Tidyverse](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_split.html).

Comment: I think this function is still not available in the `stringr` package and available maybe only in development version.

Comment: You are right. I had found this [site](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_split.html) and it looks like the manual. Now that you say it I also found [changelog](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html) and it's indeed just in the development version.

Answer (score 2):

Using `trimws` from `base R`

```
df$x <- trimws(df$x, whitespace = "\\[.*")
df$x
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b[12]", "c[34]", "d"))
```